# Unicode characters as a result of xmlhttp request

Tags: excel, vba, xmlhttprequest

In this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53106142/vba-number-of-google-news-search-results) >> @QHarr has introduced a solution to count the results of Google Search and here's the code

```
Public Sub GetResultsCount()
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.google.com/search?q=mitsubishi", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With
Set html = New HTMLDocument
With html
    .body.innerHTML = sResponse
    Debug.Print .querySelector("#resultStats").innerText
End With

End Sub
```

The code works without problems ..but in the immediate window I got this non-understandable characters
[image]

How this be fixed to appear in Arabic characters?

Thanks advanced for help

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think it depends on the [regional settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24219899/displaying-japanese-text-in-the-immediate-window-of-excel-vba)... worth a try at least, it have helped me a lot of times to change the regional settings :)

Comment: Perhaps include an image of how that part of the webpage appears for you as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this thread: [VBA - Convert string to UNICODE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23810324/vba-convert-string-to-unicode), and managed to make a solution (it works for me with Polish characters, not sure about Arabic)

```
Private Const CP_UTF8 = 65001

Private Declare Function MultiByteToWideChar Lib "kernel32" ( _
   ByVal CodePage As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
   ByVal lpMultiByteStr As Long, ByVal cchMultiByte As Long, _
   ByVal lpWideCharStr As Long, ByVal cchWideChar As Long) As Long

Public Sub GetResultsCount()
Dim sResponse As String 
Dim html      As HTMLDocument
With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    .Open "GET", "https://www.google.com/search?q=mitsubishi", False
    .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
    .send
    sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
End With
Set html = New HTMLDocument

html.body.innerHTML = sResponse
Debug.Print sUTF8ToUni(StrConv(html.querySelector("#resultStats").innerText, vbFromUnicode))
End Sub

Public Function sUTF8ToUni(bySrc() As Byte) As String
   ' Converts a UTF-8 byte array to a Unicode string
   Dim lBytes As Long, lNC As Long, lRet As Long

   lBytes = UBound(bySrc) - LBound(bySrc) + 1
   lNC = lBytes
   sUTF8ToUni = String$(lNC, Chr(0))
   lRet = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, VarPtr(bySrc(LBound(bySrc))), lBytes, StrPtr(sUTF8ToUni), lNC)
   sUTF8ToUni = Left$(sUTF8ToUni, lRet)
End Function
```

Comment: That's amazing. It works like charm. Thank you very much